# Voicemails and using the webcam through Skype

Tags: mac, skype, webcam

I can't figure out how to listen to voicemails sent to me through Skype. I've read that I should go to history, but I can't find that. I'm on Skype for Mac 5.0.0.7994

I also can't see how to switch on and off my built in webcam. If I go to **Preferences > Audio/Video**, then I see myself on the cam, but there is no option to switch it on or off. When I leave **Preferences > Audio/Video**, the camera turns itself off.

So:

1. How do I listen to voicemails? (Skype for Mac)
2. How do I turn the webcam on and off? (Skype for Mac)
3. Does the camera work when calling on Skype between a Mac and a PC? (It used not to work between Mac and PC.)

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. I can't help you with the voicemail question. I don't use Skype's voicemail.
2. You enable/disable video using the button that looks a bit like a video camera. You'll see this when you click on a contact:
   [image]

   Your mac will automatically turn on and off the webcam for you.
3. Yes, video should work from your mac to any other Skype user - on mac, windows or linux - as long as they're using a version of Skype new enough to support video calls.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience (and I'm remembering a bit of a ways back here), the voicemail showed up as almost a "chat" on the left hand pane:
(can't post images yet :( )

It's been a while, though, as I no longer pay for their services.